# Cellular neural networks

Tags: machine-learning

I'm a new at the cellular neural network, which is a special case of the recurrent neural network: my questions are:
I understand the implementation of Chua circuit for the CNN, but I still need to

1- understand intuitively why every cell in CNN receives a summation of the outputs from the surrounding cells? mathematically it is clear how to analysis it but I'm talking about the idea behind that.
2- When do we decide to change the elements of matrix A and B or one of them, since some papers they set matrix B to zeros and sometimes matrix A to zero? I know they want to reduce the error but there is something still not clear.
3-I want to use CNN to classify images and I'm looking to a good reference to do that.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: this is not really clearly written, what matrixes are you talking about? plz edit to clarify

Comment: Matrix A in all papers means feedback weight matrix, but matrix B is the feedforward weight matrix.